# Select a field that is not in Group By clause in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

could anybody help me about 
"How to select a field that is not in Group By clause in LINQ"

```
  var ReportData = 
      from a in context.Table1
      from b in context.Table2
      where a.personelID == b.ID
      && a.DateField.Value.Year == 2011
      group a by new { a.personelID, b.Name, b.Surname} into grouping
      select new
      {
           // grouping.Key.DateField,
          Name= grouping.Key.Name,
          Surname= grouping.Key.Surname,
          PagaBruto =  grouping.Sum(i => i.Bruto)),
      };
```

I can't select the field `"DateField"` that is in **Table1**, I don't want to have this field in `Group By`, because I will get a wrong result.
THANKS!

Comment: There are many `DateField` values in each group, which one do you need?

Comment: If including `DateField` in your group by clause gives the wrong results, then it seems that the elements of each grouping have different `DateField` values.  In that case, it would not be clear *which* of those values you'd want to include in the elements of the result sequence.

Comment: When you don't want use DateField in grouping, it's mean that may be in a grouping exist two or more DateField , So how to select a group by two or more DateField?

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to select both table members before you group by so you can select data from both. I did a join instead of your where clause.

```
(from a in context.Table1
 join b in context.Table2 on a.PersonalID equals b.ID
 select new { A=a, B=b } into joined
 group joined by new { joined.A.PersonalID, joined.B.Name, joined.B.Surname } into grouped
 select grouped.Select(g => new { 
                                    DateField= g.A.Datefield,
                                    Name = g.B.Name,
                                    Surname = g.B.Surname,
                                    PagaBruto = g.A.Sum(i => i.Bruto)
                                })).SelectMany(g => g);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work?

```
  group a by new { a.personelID, b.Name, b.Surname, a.DateField} into grouping
  select new
  {
      DateField = grouping.Key.DateField,
      Name= grouping.Key.Name,
      Surname= grouping.Key.Surname,
      PagaBruto =  grouping.Sum(i => i.Bruto)),
  };
```

Comment: This will also group by the date value. I believe it's not intended

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları i agree with you